# How to deduce sum's result?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, recurrence-relations

I was solving some tricky-task with algorithms and I obtained following reccurence:

$$a_{k+1} = 4a_{k} + 16^{k}, a_{1} = 1$$

It's obvious that with given start condition:
$$a_{k+1} = 4a_{k} + 16^{k} = 16^{k} + 4 \cdot 16^{k-1} + 4^{2} \cdot 16^{k-2} + 4^{3} \cdot 16^{k-3} + ... + 4^{k} \cdot 16^{0} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} { 4^{k} \cdot 16^{n-k} } =\sum_{k=0}^{n} { 4^{2n - k} } $$

This sum seems very familiar but I can't solve it - WAlpha shows as a result $\frac{1}{3}4^{n}(4^{n+1} -1)$. I assume it's easy to prove that by induction, but I'm interested in straight-forward (maybe? combinatorial) proof.

I'll be thankful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} { 4^{2n - k} }=4^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}4^{-k}$$

also, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}4^{-k}$ is the sum for a [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why the downvote? :(

Comment: I didn't downvote. However, in the future please avoid SMS abbreviations.

Comment: @rubik Thanks for the edit.  But what is SMS? :)

Comment: It wasn't mine downvote. Of course thanks - it's a shame but I  omitted such a basic way.

Comment: It's a shorthand for Short Message Service, and it refers to phone texting.

Comment: @lemoid hey, no worries, happens to the best of us :)

Comment: @rubik but when did i used an SMS????

Comment: I edited your post. Before you wrote "Can u take it from here.". I changed it into "Can you take it from here?".

Comment: @rubik sorry my bad, i'll make sure it dosen't happen happen again, bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n$ is independent of $k$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}4^{2n - k} = 4^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}4^{-k} = 4^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(\frac14)^k = 4^{2n}\cdot\frac{1 - (\frac14)^{n+1}}{1 - \frac14} = etc.$$